# How to mvn install:install-file while excluding an artifact

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'd like to `mvn install:install-file` artifact `A` excluding artifact `X`.

`A` does not depend directly on `X`, yet down the dependency tree there are several dependencies for `X`.

What would be the command to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just run install:install-file on a jar file without `-DpomFile=something`, it will create a pom with no dependencies, so there's nothing to exclude. The 'X' dependency won't be represented at all.

If you pass in a pom file via `-DpomFile=POMFILE`, then you have the dependency structure in there, and it can include whatever exclusions you need. If you put in a dependency on X, and it in turn depends on Y, you can add an exclusion to the X dependency.

A comment from the OP suggests that this has nothing to do with install:install-file.

There is some artifact 'A' with a rich and complex dependency tree, which transitively reaches some artifact 'B' at many points. How do cope with B not being available if, in fact, it's not actually needed in the classpath?

The only solution here is to add exclusions to the POMs that reference **A**. Instead of trying to change the pom of **A** to exclude **B**, you have to add the exclusion of B in your own poms as part of the dependency on A. There's no other way.

Comment: Assume A.pom is huge with hundreds of dependencies, each one with its own pom file. Do I need to set the exclusion of X in each and every one of these in A.pom?